# Executable jar is not working on other System

Tags: java, excel, selenium, executable-jar

I've created a program using Eclipse (Selenium Excel Driven Script) and exported as an executable `jar`. It runs perfectly on the computer it was written and exported on, but when I try and run it on other machines it does nothing at all. It brings up no errors, nothing at all.

I tried it by using command prompt  `java -jar filename.jar` then it is displaying error like `Excel file is not found`

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: What is your application supposed to do ?

Comment: @Berger...  Its Automation Selenium Script so script should run all flow properly.

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: @DamCx....By using Command prompt..Its shows Error as Excel file not found.And by double clicking on it ..nothing happend

Comment: Possibly your program use some files (excel, webdriver etc.) and this files are not exist on another PC, or path to file is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Can your running the jar but exporting the logs to a file `java -jar class.jar <someFile.file> 2>> log.txt`. Please share the logs if you cant still figure out